# SQL Server Query some specific condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
SELECT distinct t1.vssyspackageid,CA.rAmount as Amount,Curr.vsShortCode AS Currency       


 from tblPrograms         
   INNER JOIN tblProgramsAndPackages ON tblPrograms.vsSysProgramId = tblProgramsAndPackages.vsSysProgramId         
   inner join tblPackages t1 on tblProgramsAndPackages.iPackageId=t1.iPackageId        
  right join tblPkgContractAwardDetails as CA on CA.iPackageId=t1.iPackageId  
   join tblCurrencies as Curr on CA.iCurrency =Curr.iCurrencyId    


   where tblPrograms.vsSysProgramId='JICA'        
  group by t1.vssyspackageid,CA.rAmount,Curr.vsShortCode
```

if which package assigned to Contractor Award Detail then it will show in one column.

Example: GWSSP/01,GWSSP/02 then after it it shows total package in next column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are wanting as your question is a little vague, but I'm guessing that you want a single row for the specified Package that will show the sum of the Amount column. This is what I can understand from your question anyway!

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.vssyspackageid, 
                SUM(CA.rAmount) AS TotalAmount,
                Curr.vsShortCode AS Currency       
FROM            tblPrograms         
INNER JOIN      tblProgramsAndPackages ON tblPrograms.vsSysProgramId = 
                                          tblProgramsAndPackages.vsSysProgramId         
INNER JOIN      tblPackages AS t1 ON tblProgramsAndPackages.iPackageId = 
                                     t1.iPackageId        
RIGHT JOIN      tblPkgContractAwardDetails AS CA ON CA.iPackageId = 
                                                    t1.iPackageId  
JOIN            tblCurrencies AS Curr ON CA.iCurrency = 
                                         Curr.iCurrencyId    
WHERE           tblPrograms.vsSysProgramId = 'JICA' 
     AND        t1.[YOUR_COLUMN_NAME_HERE] = 'GWSSP/01'
GROUP BY        t1.vssyspackageid,
                Curr.vsShortCode
```

Just a few things to note:

1. I don't know the column name in the `tblPackages` table that the values such as 'GWSSP/01' belongs, so I have left that for you to fill in.
2. You will still get multiple rows if there are multiple currencies for your package, you will have to remove the `Curr.vsShortCode` from your Select and Group By clauses if that is the case.
3. I also tided up your code a bit because it was quite messy and hard to understand as well as using multiple standards and short-cuts!